# What is best product for stripping paint from wood?

Tags: painting

We want to strip previously painted trim and baseboards.  We have tried the Jasco paint stripper but it gums up and is not very successful, especially since the trim has a fairly detailed profile.  Is there a more successful product to use?

Comment: Is it antique trim? If so, it may be worth salvaging, but be careful as it likely has lead in it. It's also likely oil based paint, which may require different types of strippers. If it' NOT antique, it'll be a LOT easier just to pull it out and replace it.

Comment: The trim is original to the 1940 house, and I think there are different types of paint layers, both oil and latex.  We want to save it if possible because we only removed some of the trim from each room (where we replaced drywall), and the trim is very desirable.  There is trim still attached to the walls where we did not replace the sheetrock, so we would either need to remove and replace all trim, or attempt to strip the trim we removed and re-attach it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had better luck with strppers if you cover it with plastic food wrap after applying it. Be aware that some strippers will disolve the plastic so test a sample first,if it disolves the plastic try it with wax paper. The idea is to keep the solvents from evaporating before the paint has softened. Any latex paint should peel off easily. If you have oil based under it scuff it with some sandpaper and reapply the stripper.The sanding seems to break the "shell" and allow the stripper to penetrate. As DAO1 mentioned be cautious of lead. Avoid using a heat gun and allow for plenty of vetilation.